# elasticsearch-xml and "Failed to derive xcontent"

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have the below index:

```
curl "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v"
health status index pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   ctrlm   5   1          1            0        3kb            3kb
```

Using the below code:

```
    #conn.request("PUT", "/ctrlm/external/1?pretty", body=r'{"name": "John Doe"}', headers={"Content-type": "application/xml"})
    conn.request("PUT", "/ctrlm/external/1?pretty", body=r'<name>John Doe</name>', headers={"Content-type": "application/xml"})
    r1 = conn.getresponse()
    data1 = r1.read()
    print(r1)
    print(data1)
```

I end Up with this error:

```
b'{\r\n  "error" : "MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Failed to derive xcontent]; ",\r\n  "status" : 400\r\n}\n'
```

Yet requesting node infos:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/_all"
```

I can see among other things:

```
"plugins":[{"name":"xml-1.6.0.2-c17396e","version":"1.6.0.2","description":"XML plugin","jvm":true,"site":false}]
```

The plugin was installed this way:

```
plugin.bat --install xml --url file:C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Temp\elasticsearch-xml-1.6.0.2-plugin.zip
```

---

**Question:**

In the above if I comment the XML PUT line and un-comment the one below it works fine. It seems I can't send XML at all. What am I missing in my xml setup?